# EndOfFile in C - EOF

Tags: c

What do you put in to end the program, -1, doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//copy input to output
main() {
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Must** be [`int c;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/918959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with all other people in this thread by saying use **int c** not *char*.
To end the loop (at least on *nix like systems) you would press *Ctrl-D* to send **EOF**.

In addition, if you like to get your characters echoed instantly rewrite your code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
    {
         putchar(c);
         c = getchar();

         fflush(stdout); /* optional, instant feedback */
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you can't send a sequence of characters to represent EOF?

Comment: @Chris_45: no, EOF in this sense is "out of band", i.e. not a valid character.

Comment: How do you best describe what it is, this "out of band"-thing? /Regards

Comment: Ctrl-C / Ctrl-D / Ctrl-X etc. are used to enter special characters or send signals to your process. By pressing Ctrl-D for example you tell your program "There will be no further input, close stdin" which in turn will result in getchar() returning EOF.

Comment: for what it's worth, in windows C-Z is EOF (ie, it's end of input like C-D in linux).

Answer (score 11):

***Macro: int EOF***

This macro is an ***integer value*** that is returned by a number of functions to indicate an end-of-file condition, or some other error situation. ***With the GNU library, EOF is -1***. In other libraries, its value may be some other negative number.

Comment: On Win32 platform it is also -1 (in stdio.h) :

    #define EOF     (-1)

Comment: @Manu: That what was phoenix said, that it's a macro that evaluates to an int. The type of the literal -1 is int.

Comment: Converting int -1 to char, I think, it's also -1.

Comment: @YantaoXie thinks wrong. C standard does not mandate that the `char` is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for `getchar` is that it returns the next character available, cast to an `unsigned char` and then returned in an `int` return value.

The reason for this, is to make sure that all valid characters are returned as positive values and won't ever compare as equal to `EOF`, a macro which evaluates to a negative integer value.

If you put the return value of `getchar` into a `char`, then depending on whether your implementation's `char` is signed or unsigned you may get spurious detection of `EOF`, or you may never detect `EOF` even when you should.

Signaling `EOF` to the C library typically happens automatically when redirecting the input of a program from a file or a piped process. To do it interactively depends on your terminal and shell, but typically on unix it's achieved with Ctrl-D and on windows Ctrl-Z on a line by itself.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `int` and not `char`

Answer (score 0):

> If the integer value returned by getchar() is stored into a variable of type char and then compared against the integer constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed, because sign-extension of a variable of type char on widening to integer is implementation-defined.
>   -- [opengroup POSIX standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getchar.html)

Answer (score 0):

If char is `unsigned` by default for your compiler (or by whatever options are being used to invoke the compiler), it's likely that

```
(c == EOF)
```

can never be true.  If `sizeof(unsigned char) < sizeof( int)`, which is pretty much always true, then the promotion of the `char` to an int will never result in a negative value, and `EOF` must be a negative value.

That's one reason why all (or at least many if not all) the functions in the C standard that deal with or return characters specify `int` as the parameter or return type.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` is not an actual character or a sequence of characters. `EOF` denotes the end of the input file or stream, i.e., the situation when `getchar()` tries to read a character beyond the last one.

On Unix, you can close an interactive input stream by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. That situation causes `getchar()` to return `EOF`. But if a file contains a character whose ASCII code is 4 (i.e., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>), `getchar()` will return 4, not `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

It Still Works with **char** data type. But the tricks are checking the condition in the loop with **int** value.

***First:*** let's check it. if you write the following code like

```
printf("%d",getchar());
```

And then if you give the input from the keyboard **A** You should see **65** which is **ASCII** value of the **A** or if you give **CTRL**-**D** then see **-1**.

So that if you implement this logic then the **solving code** is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
        //printf("%c",c); // this is another way for output
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows: Ctrl+z

Unix: Ctrl+d

reference:[EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Answer (score -1):

hi i think it's becoz in a stream -1 is not one but two characters and the ascii for neither of them is -1 or whatever is used for EOF