# Why doesn't this code exit?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EndOfFile in C - EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437241/endoffile-in-c-eof)

I was trying examples from K&R. I am not able to understand why this code does not exit unless `ctrl+c` is pressed.

```
int main ( )
{
    int c; 
    c = getchar(); 
    while(c!=EOF)
        {
            putchar(c);   
            c=getchar();
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Using Windows (Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: on which system are you trying this ? Windows ? Unix ? Linux ? How do you input EOF ? (usually Ctrl+D on linux boxes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EOF is End of File. If you read from 'keyboard', you should compare to End of Line symbol which is equal to press Return

```
int main ( )
{
    int c; 
    c = getchar(); 
    while(c!= '\n')
    {
        putchar(c);   
        c=getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is easier for me to use in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, you generate end of file from the standard input stream by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Depending on the buffering behavior, you might also need to press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: +1 concise, neat and correct.

Comment: @BigMike Thanks, not correct enough to be accepted though, failed to read the original poster's mind. :)

Comment: OP asked how to trap EOF, not \n, thus this is the correct answer IMHO. If that program is used in a pipe, changing the test on EOF to a test on \n will simply break it.

Answer (score -1):

```
On Windows machine ctrl+c acts as delimiter of character scanning same as EOF 
on this loop gets broken otherwise it will keep looking for characters
```

Comment: sorry , ctrl+c should be there